# How to create dataframe only with comparison of columns in pandas where the result did not match?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe deputados_sites:

```
deputados_sites.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 512 entries, 0 to 511
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Nome              512 non-null object
Num_referencia    512 non-null object
Link              512 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 12.1+ KB
```

And another eleitos_d:

```
eleitos_d.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 513 entries, 23 to 26219
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Estado            513 non-null object
Cargo             513 non-null object
Nome_candidato    513 non-null object
CPF               513 non-null int64
Nome_urna         513 non-null object
Partido           513 non-null object
Situacao          513 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 32.1+ KB
```

I made a merge of the dataframes with the names:

```
sites_eleitos = pd.merge(deputados_sites, eleitos_d, left_on='Nome', right_on='Nome_urna')

sites_eleitos.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 341 entries, 0 to 340
Data columns (total 10 columns):
Nome              341 non-null object
Num_referencia    341 non-null object
Link              341 non-null object
Estado            341 non-null object
Cargo             341 non-null object
Nome_candidato    341 non-null object
CPF               341 non-null int64
Nome_urna         341 non-null object
Partido           341 non-null object
Situacao          341 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(9)
memory usage: 29.3+ KB
```

But I also want to create a dataframe with what was not found. The "Nome" columns in deputados_sites that were not found in the "Nome_urna" columns in eleitos_d

Show content on deputados_sites that was found on eleitos_d. I'm using. Python3 and pandas

Please, does anyone know a command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `outer` join with parameter `indicator=True` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and then filter `left_only` for rows only in `deputados_sites`, `right_only` for `eleitos_d` and `both` for rows in both `DataFrame`s by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
sites_eleitos = pd.merge(deputados_sites, 
                        eleitos_d, 
                        left_on='Nome', 
                        right_on='Nome_urna',
                        how='outer',
                        indicator=True)

ldf = sites_eleitos.query("_merge == 'left_only'").drop('_merge',axis=1)
rdf = sites_eleitos.query("_merge == 'right_only'").drop('_merge',axis=1)
bdf = sites_eleitos.query("_merge == 'both'").drop('_merge',axis=1)
```

Or by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
ldf = sites_eleitos[sites_eleitos['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
rdf = sites_eleitos[sites_eleitos['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
bdf = sites_eleitos[sites_eleitos['_merge'] == 'both'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
```